# Skill the tag between <> using regex in JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, android, regex

Hello All Developers,
         i need your help in one case so what my requirement is-
 i am trying to find a String word  in inner html using js like-

```
var  index = lcBodyinnerhtml.indexOf(Searchword, 0);
```

so my problem is that if i am try to find a word suppose "all man " and in inner html it is
 like

```
here in this world <i>all</i>man are
```

so it is not finding that word so i want that using regex or something it will skip the <> of html tag so that i 'll be able to find the exact word

Please suggest me any suitable example,thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

Html:

```
<div id="text">here in this world <i>all</i> man are all man</div>
```

Jquery / Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var searchword = 'all man';
  var text = $('#text').text();
  var repl = '<span style="color:red">' + searchword + '</span>';
  var rgxp = new RegExp(searchword, 'g');
  text = text.replace(rgxp, repl);
  $('#text').html(text);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1 minute of googling and I found this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

You can use the StrippedString to search for your Substring:

```
var OriginalString = "here in this world <i>all</i>man are" 
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
// StrippedString = "here in this world allman are"
```